# reflecting an object values which is in the memory on the GUI?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I have an object in the memory and I want to link this object with GUI component and I want this component to mirror the object status(values)....
i.e. I want to see the object values that is in the memory right now and I want the GUI to reflect the object status always
how can I do this?

Comment: Are you tying to create somthing like a debugger watch window that shows the current values of properties and fields of the object?

Comment: somthing like that but i want the value that is located on the form to change directly when the variable value change in the memory

Comment: Are you using winform or webforms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common pattern in development and is called Data Binding. .NET has some great support for data binding, it is a large topic and too big for a simple answer here. But here is a link to an MSDN article that will get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WinForms, the [`PropertyGrid` component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) is what you want:

```
public Form1() {

   // The initial constructor code goes here.

   PropertyGrid propertyGrid1 = new PropertyGrid();
   propertyGrid1.CommandsVisibleIfAvailable = true;
   propertyGrid1.Location = new Point(10, 20);
   propertyGrid1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 300);
   propertyGrid1.TabIndex = 1;
   propertyGrid1.Text = "Property Grid";

   this.Controls.Add(propertyGrid1);

   propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = textBox1;
}
```

Here, `textBox1` is being "inspected".  It can be any object.  It displays it like the property inspector you see in Visual Studio.

Comment: @ahmad, if you want it to constantly show the current value, you're going to have to use a timer to refresh it at a certain rate.  It can't liteerally be a view into that memory location, so polling will be the best you can do.